# Combine results of two SQL queries

Tags: php, sql, select, phpmyadmin, union

I want to combine the results of two queries into one `resulttable` with three columns, `result1`, `result2` and `dateday`, the queries are contradictory

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `cust` ) AS result1, DATE( `date` ) AS dateday
FROM `salg_test`
WHERE `saved` =0
AND `is_void` =0
GROUP BY dateday
ORDER BY dateday DESC

SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT `cust` ) AS result2, DATE( `date` ) AS dateday
FROM `salg_test`
WHERE `saved` =1
AND `is_void` =0
GROUP BY dateday
ORDER BY dateday DESC
```

I want both results to be grouped by and ordered by the `dateday` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT CASE `saved` when 0 then `cust` else null end ) AS result1
, COUNT( DISTINCT CASE `saved` when 1 then `cust` else null end ) AS result2
, DATE( `date` ) AS dateday
FROM `salg_test`
WHERE `is_void` =0
GROUP BY dateday
ORDER BY dateday DESC
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Im using PHPmyadmin its returning the following error: 064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND `is_void` =0 GROUP BY dateday ORDER BY dateday DESC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 5    any tips?

Comment: Sorry, deleted your where condition and forgot to change the and, try my edit.

Comment: Of course! I was blind, should have seen that myself. Thank you very much Kateract, just what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
WHERE (`saved`= 1 OR `saved`= 0)
```

Or, if the only possible values of `saved` are 1 or 0, just omit that condition from the query altogether.

Comment: Thanks for your promt answer Juan :)  I need reults of `saved`= 1 to be in one column and `saved`= 0 to be in another column, do you know how I can manage this with the OR condition?

Comment: Looks like Kateract may have the query you want.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! yes, Kateracts answer was just what i nedded :)